# ASP.NET MVC ActionResult View() not changing url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, actionresult

I have a method...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Start(SomeViewModel someViewModel) { ... }
```

that based on some conditions returns things like return `View("Invalid")`, `View("NotFound")`, `View("Run", anotherViewModel)`, etc.  The problem is that no matter what view I present, the URL does not change to reflect the new controller/action.  This poses a problem when my View wants to post to a different action.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Returning a ViewResult (by calling View(...)) essentially returns a bunch of HTML in response to the current request. If you want to change the URL, that is, have the browser GET data from a new address, you should return a RedirectResult. That's what Serge's code does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `View(...)` methods **don't** redirect, they simply render out the specific view on the current request. If you need to target a specific url in the form of your view, you can pass in the controller/action details to the form method:

```
Html.BeginForm("action", "controller")
```

... etc

Comment: +1 for being as explicit as possible about views not able to redirect.

Comment: How would this work if you had used controller.excute to redirect from a helper class or the global.asax?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to change the URL, you need a redirection to the action associated with that URL, such as

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Start(SomeViewModel someViewModel) 
{
  ...
  return RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction");
}
```

The action `SomeOtherAction` will in turn display the view.

Comment: How would this work if you had used controller.excute to redirect from a helper class or the global.asax?