# how to change url to main view when return the view because of validation errors in a PRG pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate, post-redirect-get

I've **noticed** that when the `view` is **returned** because of `validation errors` , the **url** still points to the `action` that **has done** the `validation` :

for example in `Edit View` there is a form to `Update` action:

```
@Html.BeginForm("Update","MyController",FormMethod.Post,new{})
{
...
}
```

Update action  :

```
public ActionResult Update(Entity myEntity)
{
    is(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }

    return View("Edit",myEntity);
}
```

when `validation` **fails** this shows the `Edit view` again with errors but the address is

```
   .../Update
```

am I doing something **wrong** ? how to **fix** this ?

Answer (score 3):

`am I doing something wrong ? how to fix this ?`

That's how it works, you can try `RedirectToAction` with `TempData` for model.

Like here:

[ASP.NET MVC ActionResult View() not changing url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916468/asp-net-mvc-actionresult-view-not-changing-url)

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is instead of posting it to "Update", post to the same action you are on, but mark with [HttpPost] like the following

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SomeViewModel someViewModel) {
   is(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
     return View(myEntity);
}
```

Methods with HttpPost will only get invoked when the browser detects "Post" Request. When user enters url through browser, it's a "Get" request and so the other "Edit" Action will get invoked.